# Date / Time calculations

Tags: datetime, excel-formula

I'm trying to calculate the difference in 2 dates / times.  My problem is the each date and time is in a separate column (see screenshot).  Following is the formula I have been using:

=IF(RC[-1]-RC[-4] =0,"",RC[-1]-RC[-4])

This worked until the 2  date columns weren't the same day.

I'm having trouble trying to combine the dates and time within the formula.   I could write a macro to do this or I could combine each date and time paring into one column if that makes it easier.  I'd rather not combine them as separate columns is easier for the user base.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance for your help....

[image: Date / Time Calculation]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First concatenate the Date and Time

```
=concatenate(text(A2,"mm/dd/yyyy")&" "&text(B2,"hh:mm:ss"))
```

then

**subtract them**

Other wise look at this. You can direct Subtract the dates and time without adding any extra columns

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hK1Zu.png)

```
=(CONCATENATE(TEXT(C2,"mm/dd/yyyy")&" "&TEXT(D2,"hh:mm:ss AM/PM"))-CONCATENATE(TEXT(A2,"mm/dd/yyyy")&" "&TEXT(B2,"hh:mm:ss AM/PM")))*24
```

[File Reference](https://files.fm/u/caz55dv7j)

Comment: @HSHO......Thanks.............I tried both options and it's not working like I expected.  I updated my original post with an additional screenshot.  I have hidden columns that do the concatenate (after each date / time) and then do the subtraction in the Turnaround Time column..  

So far, I've only done this to the last 2 rows.  The last row looks fine but the 2nd last row doesn't.  I was expecting around 45 hours in the Turnaround Time.  Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?  

Thanks for your help.........